# BRIN index usage

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I can not convince PostgreSQL to use my BRIN index. I have tested on PostgreSQL 14.2 and 11.1. Here is my initial setup.

```
SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Measure;    
CREATE TABLE Measure (
    id int,
    sensor_id int,
    temperature int
);

INSERT INTO Measure(id, sensor_id, temperature)
VALUES (generate_series(1, 1000000),
        round(random()*100000)::int,
        round(random()*100)::int);

DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idxbrin_measure_sensor_id;    
CREATE INDEX idxbrin_measure_sensor_id ON Measure USING brin(sensor_id);
```

When I run a simple query returning around 10 rows such as

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Measure WHERE sensor_id = 10;
```

the BRIN index is not used:

```
Seq Scan on measure  (cost=0.00..17906.00 rows=10 width=12)
  Filter: (sensor_id = 10)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A BRIN index can only be used if the logical ordering of the indexed value correlates almost perfectly with the physical ordering in the table. So it would work for the `id` column (if you never delete or update any rows), but not for `sensor_id`. Note that for a small table like that, a BRIN index is not very useful.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was able to get it work when I clustered the table according to the `sensor_id` and created the BRIN index afterward. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Laurenz Albe, the BRIN index key has to correspond to the physical ordering of the data. Therefore, I ordered the table according to the `sensor_id` and created the BRIN index, and PG used it.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_measure_sensor_id ON MEASURE(sensor_id);
CLUSTER MEASURE USING idx_measure_sensor_id;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_measure_sensor_id;
CREATE INDEX idxbrin_measure_sensor_id ON Measure USING brin(sensor_id);

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Measure WHERE sensor_id = 10;
```

In such a case the result plan is

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on measure  (cost=20.39..148083.72 rows=2 width=1016)
  Recheck Cond: (sensor_id = 10)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idxbrin_measure_sensor_id  (cost=0.00..20.38 rows=416427 width=0)
        Index Cond: (sensor_id = 10)
```